Is the optimal probability of error in discriminating $n$ states a function of the $n^2$ pairwise inner products?
I am interested in proving/understanding some relationship between state discrimination and inner products. Given a set of (pure) quantum states $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n$:
Is the optimal probability of error (PoE) in discriminating the given states -- a function of the set of $n^2$ pairwise inner products? I.e., if I know the $n^2$ pairwise inner products (without knowing the actual states), does that give me the optimal probability of error (PoE) too? This seems obvious, but I don't have a formal proof. Informally, I believe it's true because a set of $n^2$ pairwise inner products uniquely determines the equivalence class of the set of states (where two sets of states are in the same equivalence class if they can be transformed from one to another via rotation and/or renumbering which keeps the PoE equal).
[I removed the second question (to subscribe to one question/post philosophy); will post it separately sometime.]
Thanks.

Are you talking about pure states specifically, or general quantum (potentially mixed) states?

I'm primarily interested in pure states.

It's unclear what exactly the state discrimination task you have in mind is. Is $S$ known? An instructive example case to consider is $|0\rangle, |+\rangle, |+i\rangle$. The squared norm of the inner products between pairs is equal, but you can still discriminate.
It sounds like the question you are asking about is how the fidelity of the quantum states relates to the trace distance (which is a direct measure of state distinguishability).

I think the OP is rather observing that the Gram matrix $G$ (containing pairwise inner products) should be related to the optimal success probability $p^$ for a measurement to output $i$ when provided with state $\rho_i$. In your example, $G$ is diagonal $\Rightarrow p^=1$. But is there a way to determine $p^*$ in general given $G$?

@forky40 What do you mean the optimal success probability for a measurement to output $i$ when given $\rho_i$? Also, $G$ is not diagonal in the example I provided, and $p^* < 1$.

I meant that if ${h_1, \dots, h_n} := H$ is a set of positive operators, the definition I'm used to is $p^* = \max_{H \text{ is POVM}} \sum_i \text{Pr}(\rho_i) \text{Tr}(\rho_i h_i)$, which is average error. Maybe the OP meant worst-case error though, I'm not sure. And yea, forget I mentioned your example its not actually relevant to what I was saying

The minimum PoE (probability of error) in discriminating a set of given quantum states is based on an optimal POVM. The PoE is an expected value -- so, its effectively an average/sum over all pairs of possible states (assuming equal priors).  Yes, in response to the comment about the Gram matrix -- yes, that's what I mean, i.e, is p* a function of G (that's my first question)?

I have an answer to the above question (i.e., is optimal PoE (probability of error) a function of the set of inner products): Yes.

First, it is known that if two Gram matrices are equal, then the corresponding vectors are related by a unitary matrix. I.e., if vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ and $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$  have the same Gram matrix $G$, then there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $v_i = Ux_i$ for all i. (From Wiki: Horn, Roger A.; Johnson, Charles R. (2013). Matrix Analysis (2nd ed.) Theorem 7.3.11).

Second, any POVM $\Pi$ for $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ will also have a corresponding POVM $\Pi'$ (which each element of the POVM multiplied by the unitary $U$) that will incur the same PoE. Easy to verify.


